# Can't set ffmpeg header when using file for input

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to set headers ([as suggested here](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/passing-http-headers-to-ffmpeg/)) for my ffmpeg `concat` command like so:

```
ffmpeg \
    -f concat \
    -safe 0 \
    -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls \
    -headers $'Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n' \
    -i 'inputs.txt' \
    -c 'copy' 'output.wav' \
    -v trace
```

where my input file is structured as such:

```
file 'https://path/to/file1'
file 'https://path/to/file2'
file 'https://path/to/file3'
```

However, when I run the command, ffmpeg doesn't set the headers, as seen by the output of -v:

```
[http @ 0x7fa133d01080] request: GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.20.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: localhost:3001
Icy-MetaData: 1
```

What's strange is if I set my input not through an input txt and just through  `-i /path/to file` (as seen below) it works just fine.

```
ffmpeg \
    -f concat \
    -safe 0 \
    -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls \
    -headers $'Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n' \
    -i 'https://google.com' \
    -c 'copy' 'output.wav' \
    -v trace
```

Output of -v:

```
[https @ 0x7fed3ac03940] request: GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.20.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: google.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
Content-Type: audio/wav
```

Not sure why reading the inputs through a file would affect the headers getting sent. For now the workaround is to use a string concatenating all of the inputs (a bit messier than I'd like), but I'm curious if anyone might know why this is happening.

**UPDATE**: According to [this post](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21728/ffmpeg-concat-error) I have to read inputs through a text file, so I'm back to square one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a single input is directed fed to ffmpeg (`-i`), various options can be set on it, depending on what the input reader allows and recognizes.

However, FFmpeg does not natively read an input list from a text file. There's a bespoke module called the `concat demuxer`, invoked by `-f concat`, which parses the input list, opens each file and concatenates them. To the main ffmpeg pipeline, this is presented as a single input, generated by the concat module. And the concat module does not recognize or carry over options meant for the *individual files listed* within the text file. All listed files can only be opened with default parameters of their respective demuxers/decoders/protocols..etc. This is a limitation. You may open a feature request at trac.ffmpeg.org to change this.

What you could do is read all inputs directly.

```
ffmpeg \
    -headers $'Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n' \
    -i 'https://google1.com' \
    -headers $'Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n' \
    -i 'https://google2.com' \
    -headers $'Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n' \
    -i 'https://google3.com' \
    -headers $'Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n' \
    -i 'https://google4.com' \
    -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1" \
    'output.wav'
```

For WAV inputs, re-encoding to WAV won't lose quality.